# Get a nil when I check url string image

Tags: ios, swift, image, guard

I have empty **url string** from my image. I keep my **url string** image in **firestore**. But sometimes it happens that there is **no image** and I need to make a check and return an empty image.

When I load my view I get an error `nil`. Because my variable in **firestore** is empty.

It's my code:

```
guard let dataLogoImage = try? Data(contentsOf: URL(string: self.hall!.studioHallLogo)!) else { return }
```

And later I apply `dataLogoImage` to variable `tempLogoImage`.

```
self.tempLogoImage = UIImage(data: dataLogoImage)
```

How do I do a check `Data` or **empty url string** and avoid `nil`?

Comment: Never use `Data(contentsOf:)` to get data from a remote URL over the network. That initializer should only be used for local URLs of the filesystem. Use `URLSession.dataTask` to download images (or any other piece of data) from a remote URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

David is right. So here's a sample of `URLSession.dataTask` usage. This should work for you.

```
if let urlString = self.hall?.studioHallLogo,
let url = URL(string: urlString) {

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
        guard let data = data, error == nil else { return }

        // execute on main thread
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tempLogoImage = UIImage(data: data)
        }
    }

    task.resume()
}
```

As you can see, we're unwrapping your optional stuff safely, such as `self.hall?.studioHallLogo`, and the creation of your `URL` object. :) Soon you'll prolly need a library to handle image loading better and with caching. I would love to suggest: **Kingfisher**

I hope this helps. Good luck.